# SQL Server 2008 Transaction Lifecycle

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, transactions

I have a chunk of SQL code that has the following format:

```
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS ON

// Insert or Update Statement #1
GO

// Insert or Update Statement #2
GO

IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF
```

My question: is statement 1 in the same transaction as statement 2 (but that they are in different batches)? I'd believe so based on my reading on Google but I'd like some second opinions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends.
If the both statements are either one of the following   :

```
ALTER TABLE
FETCH
REVOKE
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GRANT
SELECT
CREATE
INSERT
TRUNCATE TABLE
DELETE
OPEN
UPDATE
DROP
```

then the answer is yes.

Because if the connection is already in an open transaction, the above statements do not start a new transaction.

If, however, Statement 2 is `BEGIN TRANSACTION` then it will cause two nested transactions to open.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187807(v=sql.100).aspx

And the `GO` command is just a batch separator , it doesn't start a new transaction. 
A transaction can be wrapped around multiple batches.